# THREE.js - Exported scene from editor looks different on load

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, rendering, blender

I have been working on a project in THREE.js, importing a packed GLTF into the online editor, however, when I load the exported scene in my THREE.js project, there are a couple of issues - one of the materials is all wrong (missing colour etc) and there is a strange yellow tint to another.

In the editor it looks perfect so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

here it is in the editor:

https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/5895/kBVlU0.png

and here it is in my project:

https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/4809/P9gGlJ.png

I've tried setting sRGB to true, and using no ToneMapping, but it all looks off.

Here is the application code:

```
import * as THREE from './build/three.module.js';

        import Stats from './node_modules/three/examples/jsm/libs/stats.module.js';

        import { GLTFLoader } from './node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

        import { Octree } from './node_modules/three/examples/jsm/math/Octree.js';
        import { OctreeHelper } from './node_modules/three/examples/jsm/helpers/OctreeHelper.js';

        import { Capsule } from './node_modules/three/examples/jsm/math/Capsule.js';

        import { GUI } from './node_modules/three/examples/jsm/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js';

        const clock = new THREE.Clock();

        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x88ccee );

        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ';

        const container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, } );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
        renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;
        renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
        renderer.textureEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
        renderer.toneMapping = THREE.NoToneMapping;
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        


        const stats = new Stats();
        stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
        container.appendChild( stats.domElement );


        const GRAVITY = 30;


        const STEPS_PER_FRAME = 5;

        const ray = new THREE.Raycaster();

        const worldOctree = new Octree();

        const playerCollider = new Capsule( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0.15, 0 ), new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1.5, 0 ), 0.35 );

        const playerVelocity = new THREE.Vector3();
        const playerDirection = new THREE.Vector3();

        let playerOnFloor = false;
        let mouseTime = 0;

        const keyStates = {};

        const vector1 = new THREE.Vector3();
        const vector2 = new THREE.Vector3();
        const vector3 = new THREE.Vector3();

        document.addEventListener( 'keydown', ( event ) => {

            keyStates[ event.code ] = true;

        } );

        document.addEventListener( 'keyup', ( event ) => {

            keyStates[ event.code ] = false;

        } );

        container.addEventListener( 'mousedown', () => {

            document.body.requestPointerLock();

            mouseTime = performance.now();

        } );

        document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', () => {

        //  if ( document.pointerLockElement !== null ) throwBall();

        } );

        document.body.addEventListener( 'mousemove', ( event ) => {

            if ( document.pointerLockElement === document.body ) {

                camera.rotation.y -= event.movementX / 500;
                camera.rotation.x -= event.movementY / 500;

            }

        } );

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }


        function playerCollisions() {

            const result = worldOctree.capsuleIntersect( playerCollider );

            playerOnFloor = false;

            if ( result ) {

                playerOnFloor = result.normal.y > 0;

                if ( ! playerOnFloor ) {

                    playerVelocity.addScaledVector( result.normal, - result.normal.dot( playerVelocity ) );

                }

                playerCollider.translate( result.normal.multiplyScalar( result.depth ) );

            }

        }

        function updatePlayer( deltaTime ) {

            let damping = Math.exp( - 4 * deltaTime ) - 1;

            if ( ! playerOnFloor ) {

                playerVelocity.y -= GRAVITY * deltaTime;

                // small air resistance
                damping *= 0.1;

            }

            playerVelocity.addScaledVector( playerVelocity, damping );

            const deltaPosition = playerVelocity.clone().multiplyScalar( deltaTime );
            playerCollider.translate( deltaPosition );

            playerCollisions();

            camera.position.copy( playerCollider.end );

        }


        function getForwardVector() {

            camera.getWorldDirection( playerDirection );
            playerDirection.y = 0;
            playerDirection.normalize();

            return playerDirection;

        }

        function getSideVector() {

            camera.getWorldDirection( playerDirection );
            playerDirection.y = 0;
            playerDirection.normalize();
            playerDirection.cross( camera.up );

            return playerDirection;

        }

        function controls( deltaTime ) {

            // gives a bit of air control
            const speedDelta = deltaTime * ( playerOnFloor ? 15 : 8 );

            if ( keyStates[ 'KeyW' ] ) {

                playerVelocity.add( getForwardVector().multiplyScalar( speedDelta ) );

            }

            if ( keyStates[ 'KeyS' ] ) {

                playerVelocity.add( getForwardVector().multiplyScalar( - speedDelta ) );

            }

            if ( keyStates[ 'KeyA' ] ) {

                playerVelocity.add( getSideVector().multiplyScalar( - speedDelta ) );

            }

            if ( keyStates[ 'KeyD' ] ) {

                playerVelocity.add( getSideVector().multiplyScalar( speedDelta ) );

            }



        }

        const loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

        loader.load( './scene-4.json', ( gallery ) => {

            scene.add( gallery );
            gallery.position.set(0,0,3);

            worldOctree.fromGraphNode( gallery );

            gallery.traverse( child => {

                if ( child.isMesh ) {

                    child.castShadow = true;
                    child.receiveShadow = true;
        
                    if ( child.material.map ) {

                        child.material.map.anisotropy = 4;
                    }
        
                }
        
            } );


            const helper = new OctreeHelper( worldOctree );
            helper.visible = false;
            scene.add( helper );

            const gui = new GUI( { width: 200 } );
            gui.add( { debug: false }, 'debug' )
                .onChange( function ( value ) {

                    helper.visible = value;

                } );

            animate();

        } );

        function teleportPlayerIfOob() {

            if ( camera.position.y <= - 25 ) {

                playerCollider.start.set( 0, 0.35, 0 );
                playerCollider.end.set( 0, 1, 0 );
                playerCollider.radius = 0.35;
                camera.position.copy( playerCollider.end );
                camera.rotation.set( 0, 0, 0 );

            }

        }


        function animate() {

            const deltaTime = Math.min( 0.05, clock.getDelta() ) / STEPS_PER_FRAME;

            // we look for collisions in substeps to mitigate the risk of
            // an object traversing another too quickly for detection.

            for ( let i = 0; i < STEPS_PER_FRAME; i ++ ) {

                controls( deltaTime );

                updatePlayer( deltaTime );


                teleportPlayerIfOob();

            }

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

            stats.update();

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        }
```

Any clues as to what might be happening here?

Appreciate any feedback!

Comment: I don’t see a difference, other than the camera angle. Could you specify which parts of the screenshot look wrong to you? I don’t see the material that you say is all wrong.

Comment: @Marquizzo the two material issues are the benches (do not appear to be blue), and the yellow tint to the ceiling. Asides from that it is fine, so it is just these two materials.